# How to use <select> element in php for navigating database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I've made an html page like this.
Users can select from the dropdown list, whether they want to download hall ticket or result.
But I am not able to link the options in the  tag with the database. Please help me with the php code.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table width="200" border="0"  class="download">
      <form name="download" action="downloadhalltickets.php" method="post">
        <caption align="top">
          Downloads:
        </caption>
        <tr>
          <td>Select:</td>
          <td>
            <select name="select">
            <option value="Hall Tickets">Hall Tickets</option>
            <option value="Results">Results</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Seat no.</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="seatno" maxlength="10" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="download1" value="Download" /></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to select any one between the following two php pages on select option from the above html page..

downloadhalltickets.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="downloadhalltickets.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Download Halltickets</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="mt_prakash"; // Mysql username 
$password="h.patil"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mt_test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

?>


<?php
                        $select = $_POST['select'];
      $seatno = $_POST['seatno'];
      if ($select=='Hall Tickets'){
                        $query1 ="select * from hallticket where seatno='$seatno'";
      $query2= mysql_query($query1);
                        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
?>                    

<input type="button" value=" Print this page " onclick="window.print();return false;" style="border-bottom-style:double;background-color:#FF6600;" align="right"/>
<form name="hallticket" id="hallticket" method="post" action="">
  <table width="763" id="hallticket1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="center" style="color:#3300FF"><h1>Maharashtra Tantra Niketan Shikshan Mandal</h1>
          <h3>(Established Under Govt. of Maharashtra PT Act)</h3>
        <br />
          <span style="padding:3px 5px; background-color:#3366FF; border-radius:10px; color:#FFFFFF">HALL TICKET</span>
        <p></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="37"> </td>
      <td width="170">Name:</td>
      <td width="373"><?php echo $row1['name']; ?></td>
      <td width="165" rowspan="3"><img src="" alt="Photo" name="Photo" width="86" height="92" id="Photo" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Exam Date: </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['examdate']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Exam Time: </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['examtime']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Exam Center: </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['examcenter']; ?></td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Seat No: </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['seatno']; ?></td>
      <td><img src="" alt="Signature" name="Signature" width="87" height="32" id="Photo" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>  
<?php
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

downloadresults.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Download Results</title>
<link href="downloadhalltickets.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="mt_prakash"; // Mysql username 
$password="h.patil"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mt_test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

                        $select = $_POST['select'];
      $seatno = $_POST['seatno'];
      if ($select=='Results'){
                        $query1 ="select * from result where resultseatno='$seatno'";
      $query2= mysql_query($query1);
                        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
?>                    

<table width="806"  cellpadding="10" class="upload" border="1" style="border-radius:0; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-collapse:collapse;">
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" >
  <caption align="top">
    Result upload
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <td height="62" colspan="4" align="center"><h2 style=""><img src="mtnsm.JPG" width="84" height="103" style="float:left; clear:left"/>MAHARASHTRA TANTRA NIKETAN SHIKSHAN MANDAL</h2>
      <p style="float:left" align="center"> </p>
      <h3 style="">*ONLINE RESULT</h3></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="260"> Name of Student: </td>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $row1['resultname']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Examination held in: </td>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $row1['resultlocation']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Institute Code : </td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row1['resultinstitute']; ?></td>
    <td width="327"> Seat No:    
      <?php echo $row1['resultseatno']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME OF SUBJECT: </td>
    <td width="267">MAXIMUM MARKS </td>
    <td width="302">OBTAINED MARKS </td>
    <td>GRADE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Talent search Exam </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>A1  - 91 to 100</p>
      <p>A+  - 81 to 90</p>
      <p>A    - 71 to 80</p>
      <p>B+  - 61 to 70</p>
      <p>B    - 51 to 60</p>
      <p>C+  - 41 to 50</p>
    <p>C    - 1 to 40</p></td>
    <td colspan="3"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date of Result: </td>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $row1['resultdate']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td colspan="3" align="right">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </form>
</table>
<?php
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm updating my first html code here....
Its giving the warning..
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mtnsmin/public_html/updates for centers.php:8) in /home/mtnsmin/public_html/updates for centers.php on line 27

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="updates for centers.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="icon" href="logo.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
<title>updates for centers</title>
<?php
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

if($_POST[select] == 'Hall Tickets'){
header('Location: downloadhalltickets.php');
}
elseif($_POST[select] == 'Results'){
header('Location: downloadresults.php');
}
?>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper"><span style="opacity:1"><marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="5">Welcome To Maharashtra Tantra Niketan Shikshan Sansthan</marquee></span>
</div>
<div id="tabsE">
        <ul>
                                        <!-- CSS Tabs -->
   <li><a href="Home.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="Services.php"><span>Services</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="Updates.php"><span>Updates</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="Login.html"><span>login</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="About.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
         </ul>
</div>




<table width="200" border="0"  class="download">
  <form name="download" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  <caption align="top">
    Downloads:
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <td>Select:</td>
    <td><select name="select">
 <option value="Hall Tickets" selected="selected">Hall Tickets</option>
    <option value="Results">Results</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Seat no.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="seatno" maxlength="10" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="download1" value="Download"/></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
</table>





<table width="200" border="0"  class="download">
  <form name="upload" action="students.php" method="post">
  <caption align="top">
    Uploads:
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Education:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="education" maxlength="30" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="education" maxlength="100"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" /></td>
  </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP code you already tried? You want to look for ajax requests so you can use javascript and php to get the value from the database on change

Comment: Show us your code in `downloadhalltickets.php`

Comment: SuperDJ and Jozef Duc...I've uploaded the php files too..please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I brought both the php pages on one php page and used if...else condition, and it was successfull..!!

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" value=" Print this page " onclick="window.print();return false;" style="border-bottom-style:double;background-color:#FF6600;" align="right"/>

<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="mt_prakash"; // Mysql username 
$password="h.patil"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mt_test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

                        $select = $_POST['select'];
      $seatno = $_POST['seatno'];
      if ($select=='Hall Tickets'){
                        $query1 ="select * from hallticket where seatno='$seatno'";
      $query2= mysql_query($query1);
                        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
?>                    

<form name="hallticket" id="hallticket" method="post" action="">
  <table width="763" id="hallticket1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="center" style="color:#3300FF"><h1>Maharashtra Tantra Niketan Shikshan Mandal</h1>
          <h3>(Established Under Govt. of Maharashtra PT Act)</h3>
        <br />
          <span style="padding:3px 5px; background-color:#3366FF; border-radius:10px; color:#FFFFFF">HALL TICKET</span>
        <p></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="37"> </td>
      <td width="170">Name:</td>
      <td width="373"><?php echo $row1['name']; ?></td>
      <td width="165" rowspan="3"><img src="" alt="Photo" name="Photo" width="86" height="92" id="Photo" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Exam Date: </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['examdate']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Exam Time: </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['examtime']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Exam Center: </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['examcenter']; ?></td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Seat No: </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1['seatno']; ?></td>
      <td><img src="" alt="Signature" name="Signature" width="87" height="32" id="Photo" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>  
<?php
}
}
else {
$query3 ="select * from result where resultseatno='$seatno'";
$query4= mysql_query($query3);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query4)) {
?>

<table width="806"  cellpadding="10" class="upload" border="1" style="border-radius:0; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-collapse:collapse;">
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" >
  <caption align="top">
    Result upload
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <td height="62" colspan="4" align="center"><h2 style=""><img src="mtnsm.JPG" width="84" height="103" style="float:left; clear:left"/>MAHARASHTRA TANTRA NIKETAN SHIKSHAN MANDAL</h2>
      <p style="float:left" align="center"> </p>
      <h3 style="">*ONLINE RESULT</h3></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="260"> Name of Student: </td>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $row2['resultname']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Examination held in: </td>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $row2['resultlocation']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Institute Code : </td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row2['resultinstitute']; ?></td>
    <td width="327"> Seat No:    
      <?php echo $row2['resultseatno']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME OF SUBJECT: </td>
    <td width="267">MAXIMUM MARKS </td>
    <td width="302">OBTAINED MARKS </td>
    <td>GRADE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Talent search Exam </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>A1  - 91 to 100</p>
      <p>A+  - 81 to 90</p>
      <p>A    - 71 to 80</p>
      <p>B+  - 61 to 70</p>
      <p>B    - 51 to 60</p>
      <p>C+  - 41 to 50</p>
    <p>C    - 1 to 40</p></td>
    <td colspan="3"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date of Result: </td>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $row2['resultdate']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td colspan="3" align="right">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </form>
</table>


<?php
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I might misunderstand your challenge, but I think that your making it more complicated than you need.

You could achieve it with ajax (calling the database from the page), and fetch the result or tickets that way. But if you're new to coding, then I would advise you to just do it with links.

Download results
Download tickets

... It's not as fancy as a select, but it's easier. If you want to do it with the code that you've entered, then you need to post the PHP-code you've tried with. Something along the lines of this, needs to be in the downloadhalltickets.php file:

```
<?php
if ($_POST[select] == 'Hall Tickets'){
   // PHP-code-that-lets-you-download-the-tickets
} elseif ($_POST[select] == 'Results'){ 
    // PHP-code-that-lets-you-download-the-tickets
}
?>
```

That PHP-code haven't been tested, and it's been a while, since I've coded in PHP. So beware for errors.

But I would start by doing it with links. Remember... Premature optimization is the root of all evil! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the solution....but I dont have the readymade halltickets to download from the database.  I'm calling the data for halltickets from database.  I've created two php pages one for halltickets and the other for results, I want to call anyone of the two php pages depending on the option selected by the user in the first html form from the drop down select list.

Comment: If I were you, I would probably bring those two PHP-pages together in one (so you avoid having a lot of files). But if you insist on having it in two different files, then you could set the actions to point to action="#" . And then on the same page, have something along the lines:
<?php
if($_POST[select] == 'Hall Tickets'){
  header('Location: URL-to-PHP-page-one/');
} elseif($_POST[select] == 'Results'){
  header('Location: URL-to-PHP-page-two/');
}
?>

Then the page checks, if there's a $_POST being sent, and if there are, then it'll redirect to the given page (with the header-call).

Comment: And I just realized, that these comments can't have newlines or indentation - so if you need me to write that out for you, then let me know.

Comment: I've uploaded the modified html code as per your guidance, but I'm getting a warning...and its still not working, please check if I've done any mistake or wat the warning is for...

Comment: Thanks Zeth....I thought over your idea of bringing those two php pages together.  Finally I could do what I wanted. I am posting it in the answer.

Comment: If it helped, please mark my [answer as the solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so the community can benefit from it.